# How do you input data from sql into a specific datagridview cell based on column date and name in c# winforms

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datagridview

I have a table in my database that stores data entry. theres a name column where each persons name is inserted as they scan a serial number, 3 middle columns for serial entry and the last column is the date.
database sample:

[image: 1]

i have a winform with a datagridview that populates the dates in the column header for every day of the month. what i am trying to figure out is how to populate the distinct name along with the count of their serial numbers based on what day it is in the datagridview. i can populate the names but the serial counts on specific days is getting me.
Here is what my winform looks like:

[image: 1]

and the code:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
                var startDate = new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, 1);
                int days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(dt.Year, dt.Month);
                for (int i = 0; i < days; i++)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Columns.Add("clm_" + startDate.ToShortDateString(), startDate.ToString("dd-MMM"));
                    startDate = startDate.AddDays(1);
                }
                using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(@"connection"))
                {
                    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT NAME FROM repair_data_entry", sqlConnection);
                    sqlConnection.Open();
                    SqlDataReader sqlReaderName = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (sqlReaderName.Read())
                    {
                        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(sqlReaderName["NAME"].ToString());
                    }
                    sqlReaderName.Close();
                    
                }
```

what i need to do is pull the serial count per day per tech. like Bill Berrys serial count for a specific day shows up in that specific cell. it may be a thing where i need to set the database up differently, i don't know. and that wouldn't be a problem. i should note there aren't specific names either. there's going to be 20-30 names that change on a daily basis so my intent was something dynamic.

EDIT:

I've been fiddling with SQL fiddler and I found the query that works! However, I had to hard code the dates. How would I make them dynamic based on what's in the CREATED column since techs will be entering in data on a daily basis?

Here's the query:

```
SELECT NAME AS TECH,   
[12/1/2020], [12/2/2020]  
FROM  
(SELECT NAME, REP, CREATED  
    FROM repair_data_entry) AS SourceTable  
PIVOT  
(  
COUNT(REP)  
FOR CREATED IN ([12/1/2020], [12/2/2020])  
) AS PivotTable;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8bc96/1

Comment: I am confident that you will want to do this in your query to the DB. It is unclear what values you are wanting in each cell. Where are the “Repair”, “BGA” and “Ber” values? Example… What do you want in the Bill Berry row in cell “01-Dec”?

Comment: and i think youre right.so, in the database, the serial numbers get stored. i just need a count. which i have a query for that. heres the query i use for supervisors to retrieve data and export to csv: `"SELECT NAME AS TECH, COUNT(NULLIF(REPAIR,'')) AS REPAIR, COUNT(NULLIF(BGA,'')) AS BGA, COUNT(NULLIF(BER,'')) AS BER, DATE FROM repair_data_entry WHERE DATE BETWEEN '" + dtpStart.Value + "' AND '" + dtpEnd.Value + "' AND NAME = '" + cbTech.Text + "' GROUP BY NAME, DATE";`

and i just need a count in cell "01-DEC" for bill berry for however many serials he entered in that day

Comment: It is difficult to say if the query will work, I assume it will, I am not that great at building complex queries. My point is that if you get the data from the DB using a query AND, after that, format the grid AND data to display it in a different way… then you are doing it wrong. You want to get then the data from the DB the way it should be displayed (if possible) and only “format” for cosmetic reasons. It may be complex, however the effort to build the query to return a table like the one you want would be a better approach as opposed to adding the columns, counting the serial numbers etc.

Comment: I understand. the query i posted works perfectly. i just dont know how to manipulate all that so it shows how i want. it was worth a shot though. this is what that query produces:
[query output](https://imgur.com/DLZE8PF). which is fine for one thing. I just wanted to manipulate that a bit and show it with the names on the side and each date across the column headers. and if no serials were entered that day, show a "0". super easy using google sheets haha which is what i use currently but its too cumbersome to maintain.

Comment: Try something using the last image, it should not be difficult, I can only suggest before you start is that you “create” a NEW table with the columns you want. Do NOT rebuild it “directly” using the grid, rebuild to a “new” table, then use the new table as a data source to the grid.

Comment: I'm jt tying to turn all the data into how i have it in google sheets. I know it can be done, im jst very green with this stuff and learning as i go. heres an example of what my google sheet looks like and how id want this to look...
[google sheet example](https://ibb.co/6FP3ThN)
Im able to pull the names but there has to be a code or a query that will look at the name column, look at the date row, find the cell and input data into that cell. i wish it was as easy as sheets or excel. ya know, cell A10 is where i want this data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the sql Query:

```
    DECLARE @Date AS VARCHAR(MAX),
        @query AS VARCHAR(MAX)
        
select @dATE = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CREATED, 101), '-', '/')) 
                    from repair_data_entry
                    group by CREATED
                    ORDER BY CREATED
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

SET @query = 'SELECT NAME AS TECH, ' + @Date + ' 
  
FROM  
(SELECT NAME, CREATED, REP  
    FROM repair_data_entry) AS S  
PIVOT  
(  
COUNT(REP)  
FOR CREATED IN ('+@Date+')  
) P'
EXECUTE(@query)
```

This does exactly what I want. so that answers that.
[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8bc96/41)

can anyone point me in the direction to change the date style to "MM / dd / yyyy"?

EDIT: found the answer. updated query